# Java: Vector sort vs Collection sort

Tags: java, sorting, vector, collections

I have never had the pleasure to work with the code below, and I've now stumbled upon an assignment where I'm suppose to argument which of these is most used, and why.

We've got two examples,

```
public Vector<Integer> sort(Vector<Integer> integers) { ... }

public Collection<Integer> sort(Collection<Integer> integers) {}
```

Essentially, we're to argument which of these two examples is the best solution to sorting things. Which of these two are used the most, and why?

Comment: Vector is obsolete. use Collection

Comment: But why, friend? I'd like more than that, if possible.

Comment: @aTON I think you were meant to think about the answer, instead of asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: Although the `Vector` version is clearly inferior due to using `Vector`, I wonder whether the same would apply to `ArrayList`. The problem with the generic version is what collection it returns.

Comment: `As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.`

Comment: Thus spake the API documentation of `Vector`. (Which should be your first port of call really.) I personally would add that even if a thread-safe implementation is needed, you should avoid `Vector`.

Comment: use `Collections.sort()` provided by Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List) also, it's a better solution to use `Collection` because `Vector` is a concrete class, while `Collection` is an interface, therefore the method is not tightly coupled to the subclass...

Comment: @Kayaman Of course, but I'm totally clueless here, that's why I turned here. People here tend to explain a tad better.

Comment: Vector uses synchronization which in most cases is not required and has performance impact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Essentially, we're to argument which of these two examples is the best solution to sorting things. Which of these two are used the most, and why?

Lots of comments but I don't see an answer really. So: the second one is more used nowadays. The first one is an old method, back from the early Java days. You can still use it, but nowadays people use mostly the second one because it obviously imposes less requirements on the person using it (in particular the collection which you're sorting doesn't need to be a `Vector`).

Answer (score 0):

There are advantages and disadvantages to each.  I think you're being asked to choose (perhaps deliberately) between two poor choices.

As many have already said, Vector is obsolete.  It should not be used.

However… there's a reason the [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) method takes a List and not a Collection:  How does one sort an unordered Set?  How would one sort a collection which already has a required order, like a TreeSet?

Since the notion of sorting a Collection is so poorly defined, the method which takes a Vector is probably the better one to use, even though Vector itself shouldn't be used.